# Dynamic Layout with respect to add and remove fields

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, angularjs, spring

My client has a requirement of a self service portal. After the application is deployed with initial requirements , he want to manage him self by adding or removing fields by himself. he is asking for such kind of control.

Ex - we deliver the login page with his initial requirements , later if he want to add a new field in the login page , he wants to have an admin page where he will select login page for the changes , he will describe the type of the new field inside , he is expecting that application will guide to select the type of field as dropdown , if he does that then application will prompt to enter the list of the values , application will ask if that feild is mandatory or not and so on. is this kind of genericness is really possible using angular or other applications.

Also we have migration requirements ,where we need to migrate huge data from legacy system. if this kind of dynamic ness is feasible , is it also feasible to migrate the huge data include the dynamically created fields using the application.

appreciate your support in helping me in this , I am kind of wondering is this even possible and can be maintained flawlessly.

Thanks,

Looking for possible solutions from the experts

Comment: It looks like the possibility for a client to manage web app content can be provided by integrating CMS into your project. I suppose you would need to look towards headless CMSs which are platform-independent and potentially should work the best for migration.

Comment: Yes it is possible to dynamically render fields (inputs) their metadata are loaded from the database. Angular has multiple ways to achieve that. You just need to have a look at how angular works.

Comment: Thanks @MehyarSawas , i will explore further. I hope in long term this kind of implementation can work with out hassles as we will end up with many feilds and they are to be stored and then business logics to be written later. Thanks !